# Less: how to write :hover and :focus

Tags: css, less

I just started learning Less and would like to have an outcome like this:

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
   /* some rules */
} 

.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
   /* some rules */
} 

.navbar .nav > li > a:focus {
   /* some rules */
}
```

I can't figure out how to write that in Less. I tried

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    /* some rules */
    &:hover {

    }
    &:focus {

    }
}
```

but that doesn't work. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: That is the right way to do that.

Comment: So what do you get if it doesn't work?

Comment: It works just fine. http://www.dopefly.com/less-converter/less-converter.html

Comment: Try to elaborate more than "that doesn't work."

Answer (score 58):

That is the essentially the correct format for nesting, but it is a little unclear what you are expecting. Perhaps you are expecting *duplication* of the `/* some rules */` into the `:hover` and `:focus` (just based on what you show above for input and output--***if that is not a correct understanding of your issue, please clarify***). However, that is not how nesting works. Nesting only picks up the selector string to attach the pseudo class to, it does not populate the rules defined *outside* of it automatically *into* it. You need to be more explicit like one of these options:

**Option 1 (using nesting)**

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    /* some rules */
    &:hover {
      /* some rules */
    }
    &:focus {
      /* some rules */
    }
}
```

**Option 2 (just like CSS)**

```
.navbar .nav > li > a,
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar .nav > li > a:focus {
    /* some rules */
}
```

**Option 3 (using nesting with a mixin)**

```
.setRules() {
    /* some rules you type once */
}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
    .setRules();
    &:hover {
      .setRules();
    }
    &:focus {
      .setRules();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to `LESS`, but I think options 2 and 3 are better because they minimise duplication.

Comment: I agree completely, I put option 1 in as it was more parallel to his initial question format. If I have understood the question correctly, the options 2 or 3 would be best to reduce code duplication.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Sorry I didn't clarify first of all that I use Less javascript to do the conversion on the fly. And I didn't get any output for the :hover and :focus. 

@ScottS, I don't expect the repeat of the rules because I know it will be inherited anyway.

Matt Ball I tried the coverter you suggested and it spit out correct output as I expected. So it means there is an issue with the Javascript on the fly conversion?

Comment: Sometimes there are rules set again on `:hover` etc. so that no other `:hover` rules on `<a>` elements override what you want to remain, so I was not sure if that was your intent. However, it does sound like whatever your javascript is doing to "convert" is your issue. You may want to either clarify this question or pose another dealing with the issue you are facing in more detail.