# Adding hover to a HTML Section Element LESS

Tags: css, less

I have a HTML section element which is defined as below:

```
<section class="sectionClass">
  <h2>
      some text
   </h2>
</section>
```

```
.sectionClass {
  h2 {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Now, when the page loads the h2 is not displayed which is obvious. Now, I want that when I hover on the section the h2 is displayed and then when I dont hover then it hides. How can I do that using LESS?

UPDATE:

I added the following code but it does not show the h2 element even when I hover on the section.

```
.sectionClass :hover {
  h2 {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Comment: `&:hover` would be the key here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Less: how to write :hover and :focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356049/less-how-to-write-hover-and-focus)

Answer (score 3):

Add the `:hover` pseudo class to the parent `.sectionClass:hover h2` [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/6m00o3g1/).

You can achieve this by using the [`&` operator](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature), which essentially references the parent selector.

```
.sectionClass {
  &:hover {
    h2 {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  h2 {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
.sectionClass:hover h2 {
  display: block;
}
.sectionClass h2 {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Sweet! &:hover was the syntax that I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @johndoe this question has been asked a dozen times on SO, please use the search function next time...;)

Comment: @Christoph But sometimes it's hard to search for something when you don't know what the feature is called.

Comment: I understand - however I did a plain "use :hover in less" search on google and found several SO questions regarding this topic. Well, maybe next time;) If this answer solves your problem, feel free to check it, to mark your question as solved.